# creating a URL that links to a specific location in a custom google map

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink

I have been using the google maps API to create a custom google map entirely based on my own images, and have found ways to make markers or HTML div elements zoom in on specific locations. However, I am wondering is there any way to create a URL link that links directly to a location and zoom level on the map?

The idea being that if one were to click on a different link (from outside the site) one would enter the site straight at a specified location, instead of the default location.

I know this is already possible with links taken from the original google maps (as opposed to custom versions), is it possible with the API?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not possible with any API-methods, you must parse the url on your own .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current API, no. But you can use [the URLON library](https://github.com/vjeux/URLON) to easily build and parse an object in the URL - which you can use to set your map options.

Essentially you use the `URLON.parse()` method to parse your hash in the URL. Then use the attributes in the generated object to set your `google.maps.MapOptions` on load. Putting it together will yield:

```
//remove the # from the hash string, as URLON starts parsing from the underscore
urlMapOptions = URLON.parse(hash.substr(1, hash.length));

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: (urlMapOptions.zoom) ? parseFloat(urlMapOptions.zoom) : 8,
    center: (urlMapOptions.lat && urlMapOptions.long) ? new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(urlMapOptions.lat), parseFloat(urlMapOptions.long)) : new google.maps.LatLng(43.7, -79.4),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Here is the link to the map, which defaults to Toronto and a zoom level of 8: http://svignara.github.io/loadgmapwithlink.html

And here is the link to the map, which loads the center to Chicago at a zoom level of 12: http://svignara.github.io/loadgmapwithlink.html#_lat=41.8819&long=-87.6278&zoom=12

Link to github repo: [html](https://github.com/svignara/svignara.github.com/blob/master/loadgmapwithlink.html), [JS](https://github.com/svignara/svignara.github.com/tree/master/projects/loadgmapwithlink/js).