# How can I create a custom, shareable and colaborative map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

My situation is this: I have my API code and my website running, then I can load a map, access it from JavaScript and create overlays or functions, but I'm trying to store (save) these custom markers (overlays obtained from script) in a map in a permanent way, but I'm unable to do it as every time I refresh my webpage the markers (and all overlays) disappear and the map reloads without any overlays or any markers, and I don't know how can I solve this.

**How can I create a custom, shareable and colaborative map?**

Note that I can get a map and create temporary overlays through a JavaScript in my website, but I can't save (store) these overlays or create permanent markers.

Is it possible do it through JavaScript Code (API v3) direct in my website?

Do I need to purchase a Map Engine (for Business) license?

I would not like to use my own database, but use something based on a Google Maps, like a layer e.g., where I could store markers. Is there any way? Google Maps Engine does this?

I've been reading something about "layerID" and "MapID" from Maps Engine (for business) where I think it would be possible to store custom markers (and drawings)  in a custom layer direct in google maps Engine. But I didn't find anything about this in internet and I don't have access to Maps Engine (for business) to try.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702863/creating-a-url-that-links-to-a-specific-location-in-a-custom-google-map/18710316#18710316). You can store all your overlay options in the URL using the [URLON Library](https://github.com/vjeux/URLON), then load them in on page load - it's basically like preserving your save state in the URL itself (making it shareable).

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)

These two articles will allow you to collect data from InfoWindows, and display data from the database on a map (make the data persistent):

- [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)
  Shows how to use PHP/MySQL and the Google Maps API v3 to create a map that polls data from a database and shows as markers.
- [From Info Windows to a Database: Saving User-Added Form Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3)
  Shows how to prompt users to fill out information in an infowindow, and then save that information back into a database.

Extend to save and retrieve data from the [Drawing Manager](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) if you need to save other geographic data besides markers.

Comment: I would not like to use an external database, but use something based on Google maps, like a layer e.g..  Is there any way? Google Maps Engine? To create a layer? Is there any way to store drawings (markers) direct in a custom map or layer?